# X3D: how to add coordinates dynamically into DOM for a IndexedFaceSet?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, x3d, x3dom

This is my x3d dom context:

```
<x3d>
  <Scene>
      <Shape>
        <Appearance>
          <Material diffuseColor="0 0 1" emissiveColor="0 0.5 0" shininess="0.8" specularColor="0.5 0.5 0.5"/>
        </Appearance>
        <IndexedFaceSet id="idxFS">
          <!--Coordinate point with values dynamically when function addFaces() is called-->
        </IndexedFaceSet>
      </Shape>
   </Scene>
</x3d>
```

This is my `function addFaces()` which is called when a button is pressed

```
function addFaces()
{
  let faces = document.getElementById('idxFS');
  faces.setAttribute('coordIndex', '0 1 2 3 -1 7 6 5 4 -1 0 4 5 1 -1 1 5 6 2 -1 2 6 7 3 -1 3 7 4 0');

  let coords = document.createElement('Coordinate');
  coords.setAttribute('point', '-2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 -2.0 -2.0 2.0 -2.0 -2.0 -2.0 2.0 2.0 -2.0 2.0 2.0 -2.0 -2.0 -2.0 -2.0 -2.0');

  faces.appendChild(coords);
}
```

But the part with the coordinates does not work. If I put the coordinates static into the DOM it works. like it can be seen here https://www.web3d.org/x3d/content/examples/ConformanceNist/Geometry/IndexedFaceSet/default_facesetIndex.html

But my dynamic version does not work. Help would be much appreciated!! I've tried for hours now but I could not get it to work.